# Flash video stream pixelating when downloading player, just fine when player is local

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, download, video-streaming

I'm building videochat functionality for a site, using Wowza as the streaming server.  I've noticed that when I use the chat on a page hosted on another machine (EC2 in this case) it pixelates, but when I just view a local html file referencing a local copy of the player, there's no problem.  I'm not sure why, because even the local copy of the player is sending an outgoing video stream and reading another stream from the streaming server.  The only differences between the perfect quality/annoyingly pixelated versions are:

The actual page is hosted locally/nonlocally
The .swf file is hosted locally/nonlocally.

Does anyone know if downloading the flash player degrades the streams that play in it?  And if so, is there any way to get around this?

Comment: can you post a link to watch the pixelating player?

Comment: is it happening while viewing the swf in the Flash IDE or is it while in your browser? (the local version)

Comment: which player do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I could be off-base here, but I don't think it should have anything to do with where you're hosting the files.  You might just be running into network bandwidth issues.  Flash will modify the quality of the camera stream by default to prioritize frameRate rather than image quality.  To change that, you'll have to set:

Camera.setQuality(); // try with Camera.setQuality(0, 100);

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#setQuality()